# Does the use of many rails associations cause significant memory growth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a Rails active job running on a Heroku dyno via Sidekiq.

When the job runs, the memory grows from 150MB to 550MB.
I found out the cause was n+1 queries to the DB, and fixed it by doing my calculations on the data in the DB query instead of in the code.

Afterwards I wanted to refactor a bit, as I generally like to keep the SQL somewhat simple, and have the logic in the code. For this reason I switched my "joins" with "includes", which allows me to use the associations of the objects. It turned out though that this refactoring introduced the memory issue once again though.
So my conclusion is, that it is the use of the associations that causes the memory growth, as the number of SQL queries are the same after I fixed the N+1 issue. Please note the job handles a lot of objects, around 250.000. It seems reasonable c.f. the delete vs. destroy functionality where delete performs better as the objects themselves are not instantiated as they are with destroy.

Is my conclusion accurate, or am I missing something?

Thanks,
-Louise

Comment: I think if you use `includes` that will still take initial time as it needs to eager load all the objects you want

Comment: I'm guessing you're not using [ActiveRecord::Batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)? There is no good reason why you should be working with  250.000 objects at once.

Comment: May be post some code so that we can actually analyze what you are doing but instantiating 250k records is going to consume memory no matter what. Not sure exactly what you are doing but unless you need all of these objects in memory at the same time for some reason it would be better to iterate and dispose as @max pointed out you can use `ActiveRecord::Batches` for this. If no interaction at all is need then a SQL only solution would be far less memory consumptive, but without understanding what you are doing it is nearly impossible to help or to even answer this question

Comment: In order to be able calculate statistics, I need information from all the records (conditions, numbers to summarize etc.). I did not know about the Batches feature though, so I will definitely have a look at that - thank you for the reference!
I know the question was quite vague, but at this stage I was just wondering whether it sounds reasonable that the difference in using associations, and not using associations for that amount of rows is roughly around 350MB. I totally understand if that is too much to ask with the given information. Thanks again for the Batches reference!